# How can I enable trimming when using SignalR as a client?

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr, .net-7.0

I have a small .NET application that uses SignalR to communicate with a server. I just quickly tried to upgrade it to .NET7 (from .NET6) and enabled trimming using the following in the csproj file:

```
<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
```

This fails, I get errors like this from the SignalR code

> Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported.

I tried finding out if SignalR can work with trimming, but I was not able to find any statements on this. I know there are ways to adapt JSON serialization with System.Text.Json to work with trimming and AOT, but I did not see anything about SignalR. But as far as I understand the main issue for SignalR would be the serialization, so the solution might be similar.

I don't want to try something impossible though, this is a pretty new feature with sparse documentation and I don't know this area of .NET very well. It would be really useful to make the binary smaller in this case, if it were possible with a reasonable amount of effort.

So, is what I'm trying to do possible with the current .NET7 versions of SignalR? Can I set it up in a way to enable trimming in my binary without breaking it? And if yes, how do I need to adapt the SignalR code to work with trimming enabled?

Comment: Work to enable trimming in the SignalR client hasn't been done yet. It's very much an uncharted territory if you try it out.